# take elements from tree and keep middle nodes

Tags: php

I have tree in array which looks like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 28
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [name] => ccc
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 29
                                    [parent_id] => 28
                                    [name] => aaaa
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 32
                                    [parent_id] => 28
                                    [name] => bbb
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )                        )

                }
        }
}
```

And i want to get some of nodes but with parents for example

if i have tree like that

```
1
 ---2
 ---3
    ---4
    ---5
 ---6
```

and I am interested in  {1,2,4} i want to get

```
1
---2
---3
   ---4
```

so i need nodes from my array and all nodes on path between my nodes but i don't have idea what can I do this

Comment: you need only the first child of the node ?

Comment: You need to walk through the ancestors of all nodes you are interested in and put them (and the child) into a list, then traverse your entire tree removing nodes that are not in the list.

Comment: can you clarify more about the expected output ? Also it will be easy if you show the script where this ayyay is being generated